# Programmatically draw (and label) a triangle's angle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw and label angle A (alpha) of my ABC triangle while still being able to change to coordinate of A B and C so that the angle and the mark adapts to it.

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetkzobj{all} %also needed
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \coordinate (M) at (0,0) ;
 \coordinate (A) at (canvas polar cs:angle=90,radius=3cm) ;
 \coordinate (B) at (canvas polar cs:angle=-30,radius=3cm) ;
 \coordinate (C) at (canvas polar cs:angle=30,radius=3cm);
 \draw (M) circle (3cm);
 \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) --cycle;
 \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M);
 \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,C);
 \tkzLabelPoints(B,M);
 \tkzMarkAngle[fill= red,size=1.5cm, opacity=.4](B,A,C); %thanks to Claudio
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.8](B,A,C){$\alpha$};  
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: have a look at `tkz-euclide`. It's the best tool for such constructions

Comment: I think [TikZ: Create right angle triangle with angle labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96459/13304) is a good starting point.

Comment: In a question I asked some time ago (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124426/32245) there have been some nice solutions for calculated triangles and autorotated angle labels and so on...

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/best-way-to-create-this-image-square-and-angle/34673#34673 for some solutions.

Comment: You can answer your own question below as a *self-answer* but, please, **do not edit your question to include the answer in it**. If you do, your question becomes incomprehensible to future visitors of this page. You want to leave them a trail of breadcrumbs as to what the problem originally was---that entails leaving your MWE intact, warts and all---before showing how it can be solved.