# How to draw a irregular circle(shape)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots

I want to draw some irregular circle(shape) in my wireless scenario.

with a basestation in the center.

around is some irregular circle(shape).

I find something(could be used) in this web(but I feel it's size is too large)

---

Now my teacher want me use this circle as small as possible, but I find when I turn the radius  smaller, the irregularcicle's round isn't clear so much. Is there any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your latest request. What is the problem with small irregular circle? Can you show a picture?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With PSTricks (just for typing exercise).

### Single

[image]

- Verbose:

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
  \pstVerb{realtime srand}
  \psset{plotpoints=50}
  \def\points{}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
      \curvepnodes{0}{360}{Rand 1.50 add t PtoC}{X}
      \multido{\i=0+1}{\Xnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (X\i)}}
      \expandafter\psccurve\points
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Compact:

  `\psnccurve` is a new macro (among others) in `pst-node` to pass an array of nodes to  `\psccurve` without creating the concatenating macro `\points` (as used in the code above). Now I can save more keystrokes.

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
  \pstVerb{realtime srand}
  \psset{plotpoints=50}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
      \curvepnodes{0}{360}{Rand 1.50 add t PtoC}{X}
      \psnccurve(0,\Xnodecount){X}
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

### Multiple

[image]

- Verbose:

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
  \pstVerb{realtime srand}
  \psset{plotpoints=50}

  \begin{document}
  \psLoop{10}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
      \curvepnodes{0}{360}{Rand 1.50 add t PtoC}{X}
      \def\points{}% empty for each iteration
      \multido{\i=0+1}{\Xnodecount}{\xdef\points{\points (X\i)}}
      \expandafter\psccurve\points
  \end{pspicture}}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Compact:

  ```
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
  \usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
  \pstVerb{realtime srand}
  \psset{plotpoints=50}

  \begin{document}
  \psLoop{10}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
      \curvepnodes{0}{360}{Rand 1.50 add t PtoC}{X}
      \psnccurve(0,\Xnodecount){X}
  \end{pspicture}}
  \end{document}
  ```

### Notes

`\psnline`, `\psncurve`, and `\psnccurve` are available but `\psnpolygon` is not.

### Attention

Note that `Rand` no longer produces a random real number between 0 and 0.5 inclusive. Its definition had been tacitly changed. Now it produces a random real number between 0 and 1 inclusive. It is not documented, nor announced, but it is still fun!

The code given above has not been updated yet so it will produce different output. I have no time to update it right now. Sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my means.
I still hope the second answer's function.
But still thanks a lot!!

Comment: @facebook-703000782: I still don't understand your question even though I have read it multiple times. My answer was created based on the output given by other answers.

Comment: The correct code is `\psnccurve(0,\numexpr\Xnodecount-1){X}` because `Xnodecount=plotpoints-1`, the first and last points have the same coordinates in a closed curve, so `\psnccurve` only needs the first `plotpoints-2=Xnodecount-1` points.

Answer (score 37):

Using the `rand` function, you can write the `\irregularcircle` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\irregularcircle[2]{% radius, irregularity
  \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
  +(0:\len pt)
  \foreach \a in {10,20,...,350}{
    \pgfextra {\pgfmathsetmacro\len{(#1)+rand*(#2)}}
    -- +(\a:\len pt)
  } -- cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (d) at (1,2);
  \draw[blue,rounded corners=1mm] (c) \irregularcircle{1cm}{1mm};
  \draw[red,rounded corners=1mm] (d) \irregularcircle{1cm}{1mm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** a variant using `let` operations (from the `calc` library):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\irregularcircle[2]{% radius, irregularity
  let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(#2)} in
  +(0:\n1)
  \foreach \a in {10,20,...,350}{
    let \n1 = {(#1)+rand*(#2)} in
    -- +(\a:\n1)
  } -- cycle
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (d) at (1,2);
  \draw[blue,rounded corners=.5mm] (c) \irregularcircle{1cm}{1mm};
  \draw[red,rounded corners=.5mm] (d) \irregularcircle{1cm}{1mm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Paul, your answer is exactly I want. THX a lot!!!

Comment: This is very interesting. I have asked a [related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359844/5590) and a [follow-up question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359947/5590) regarding how the definition of the macro `\irregularcircle` works.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `plot`:

```
  \documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw  plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates {(-3.5,0.5) (-3,2.5) (-1,3.5) (1.5,3) (4,3.5) (5,2.5) (5,0.5) (2.5,-2) (0,-0.5) (-3,-2) (-3.5,0.5)};
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw  plot[smooth, tension=.8] coordinates {(-2.5,-0.5) (-3.5,0) (-2.5,0.5) (-3,1) (-2,1.5) (-2,3) (-1,2.5) (1,4.5) (2.5,3) (3,3.5) (3.5,3) (3,2) (4.5,2) (4.5,0) (3,1) (2.5,-0.5) (3.5,-1.5) (1.5,-1) (0.5,-2) (-2,-2.5) (-1.5,-1) (-2.5,-1.5) (-2.5,-0.5)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Using the same points as above the curve can be drawn using the excellent `hobby` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
        \draw (-3.5,0.5) .. (-3,2.5) .. (-1,3.5).. (1.5,3).. (4,3.5).. (5,2.5).. (5,0.5) ..(2.5,-2).. (0,-0.5).. (-3,-2).. (-3.5,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
        \draw (-2.5,-0.5).. (-3.5,0).. (-2.5,0.5).. (-3,1).. (-2,1.5).. (-2,3).. (-1,2.5).. (1,4.5).. (2.5,3).. (3,3.5).. (3.5,3).. (3,2).. (4.5,2).. (4.5,0).. (3,1).. (2.5,-0.5).. (3.5,-1.5).. (1.5,-1).. (0.5,-2).. (-2,-2.5).. (-1.5,-1).. (-2.5,-1.5).. (-2.5,-0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Choose points as you wish and leave the rest to `hobby`. For more details, use `texdoc hobby` or [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/).

Comment: Nice :-) Where is the `hobby` library documented?

Comment: @Tobi `texdoc hobby` :)

Comment: Thank. I thought TikZ libraries can’T be found via `texdoc` and are documented as part of the `pgfmanual`. Btw. `hobby` seems to be not yet listed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42611/4918 …

Comment: @Tobi `hobby` is not an official part of `pgf`, i.e., it is not in `tex/generic/pgf/libraries/` or `tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/` but is distributed as a package of its own (in `tex/latex/hobby/`).

Answer (score 12):

Paul Gaborit's answer is a bit outdated. Now the `rand` function is `rnd` and there's the `decorations` library which can be used to make irregular circles with sharp irregularities.

For smooth irregularities the `plot` path specifier (used by user11232) can be used along with the `rnd` function too, removing the necessity to create coordinates. The below MWE presents both solutions.

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);

    \draw[decoration={random steps, amplitude=2mm}, decorate] (4.5,0) circle (2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution for ellipse and it also works. I have also tried different amplitudes but the ellipse results with spikes and I would like more rounded random variations in the ellipse shape. Do you know how to get more rounded variations?

Comment: Did you make this ellipse with `plot` and used the `smooth cycle` option? In order to get the smooth variations in radius you need to plot the ellipse with that option. This works for me: `\draw plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5 and 1+rnd*0.5)` (2 is the `x` radius while 1 is the `y` radius)

Comment: Thank you it works form me. I did not know about `smooth cycle` option.