# Sequence of images in the tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I am trying to design a sequence of diagrams as given in the image attached below. Till now I have been able to do this much.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{}
\[
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
\begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
\cdot &    &    &  &  &  \\
\hline
&    &    &  &  &  \\
&    &  & &  &  \\
&  & &  &   &  \\
&  &  &  &   &  \\
&  & &  &   &  \\
\end{array} 
\]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=black] (16.1,5.5) rectangle ++(2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am trying this [image: ence]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `tizpicture`, using `pic` and TikZ libraries `arrows.meta`, `positioning` and `shapes.symbols`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % it load amsmath
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.symbols
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Process \dots}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick, shorten > = 1mm, shorten < = 1mm},
   box/.style = {draw, minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm},
 oblak/.style = {cloud, draw, aspect=2},
   TAB/.pic   = {\draw (0,0) -- (1.5,0);
                 \draw (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,-2.5);
                 \coordinate (-w) at (1.5,-1);
                }
                        ]
\pic    (n1) at (0,0) {TAB};
\node   (n2) [box, right=of n1-w] {text};
\node   (n3) [oblak, right=of n2] {text};
\node   (n4) [box, right=of n3]   {text};
\draw[arr]  (n1-w) edge (n2) (n2) edge (n3) (n3) to (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
in the case, that `array` in your MWE is intended that will be filled with dome text, than `pic` had to be replaced with `array` as is done in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % it load amsmath
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.symbols
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Process \dots}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 9mm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick, shorten > = 1mm, shorten < = 1mm},
   box/.style = {draw, minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm},
 oblak/.style = {cloud, draw, aspect=2},
                        ]
\node   (n1) [box, draw=none] {$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
                                x   & 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
                                    &&&         \\
                                    &&&         \\
                                    &&&
                                \end{array}$};
\node   (n2) [box, right=of n1] {text};
\node   (n3) [oblak, right=of n2] {text};
\node   (n4) [box, right=of n3]   {text};
\draw[arr]  (n1) edge (n2) (n2) edge (n3) (n3) to (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `tabular` and the `shrink` option for `frame`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=cyan!90!black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=30]

\frametitle{}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
$\begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
\cdot & & & & &  \\
\hline
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
& & & & &  \\
\end{array} $

& $\to$ &

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1.5cm]
\draw[draw=black] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\node at (1,1.5) {text1};
\end{tikzpicture}

& $\to$ &

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm]
\draw plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:1+rnd*0.5);
\node at (0,0) {text2};
\end{tikzpicture}

& $\to$ &

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=1.5cm]
\draw[draw=black] (0,0) rectangle ++(2,3);
\node at (1,1.5) {text3};
\end{tikzpicture}

& $\to$ &

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm]
\node at (0,0) {text4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

The vertical alignment of the text and arrows may not be to your satisfaction, but you can adjust that with the `baseline` option for the `tikzpicture` environments. I was also lazy and put the last text in a `tikzpicture` all by itself, but it doesn't have to be, though then you have more alignment issues (which in turn can be solved with `\raisebox`, but not prettily).

You can make longer arrows with `\longrightarrow` or just a `tikz` arrow, which can be any length / style.

Irregular shape taken directly from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350388/19372).

Comment: How to increase the size of the arrows

Comment: @niceguy change every `$\to$` to `\tikz{\draw[->] (0,0)--(1,0);}`. Change the `1` to something bigger to make the arrow longer.