# Is there an extensive library of arrow tips with a standardized naming convention?

Tags: symbols, diagrams, arrows

I am drafting diagrams where I need a lot of different arrow tips to indicate different types of directionality. Currently I am using a mixed set of libraries, which I mainly found through
[detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). The result is that I am using mathmode arrows like `\leftrightarrow`, or `\leftrightarrows` from the `amsmath` package. 
If I am not able to find an arrow tip, I make my own such as:

```
\newcommand{\dentedarrowicon}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
    \draw [-] (1,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw [-] (2,1) -- (1.7,0.7) -- (2.5,1) -- (1.7, 1.3) -- (2,1) ;
    \fill (2,1) -- (1.7,0.7) -- (2.5,1) -- (1.7, 1.3) -- (2,1) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This will draw
[image]

Instead of scrapping around for different arrow tips, I would like to have unified library which I could apply. More importantly I need a naming convention for arrow tips. The "dentedarrowicon" is a term I made up and still, in my opinion, is a bit descriptive. 
This changes however when I start describing [image] as `open arrow with tbar`

```
\newcommand{\openarrowwithtbaricon}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50]
    \node (datanode2)[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, shape border rotate=270,scale=0.5]  at (2,1) [draw,thick, fill=white] {};
    \draw [-] (1,1) -- (datanode2);
    \draw [-] (1.7,0.7) -- (1.7,1.3); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Is there an extensive library with arrowtips I could use, with a standardized and descriptive naming convention? I am aware of a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42679/13715), where the TikZ library is mentioned. It is a great answer, but I still need a lot more types of arrowtips and I am not sure if an `open triangle 60` is a descriptive name.

Anyone knowing either an extensive library of arrowtips or a standard naming convention I can use to draft my own?