# Recreating this TikZ image

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to recreate the following image in TikZ.
[image: Tikz Drawing]

I'm able to draw the boxes using the following TikZ code, but I'm unable to correctly place the underbraces and the symbols.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1.6,0) -- (1.6,1.3) -- (0,1.3) -- (0,0);
\draw (1.7,0) -- (3.3,0) -- (3.3,1.3) -- (1.7,1.3) -- (1.7,0);
\draw (3.4,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,1.3) -- (3.4,1.3) -- (3.4,0);
\draw (5.1,0) -- (6.7,0) -- (6.7,1.3) -- (5.1,1.3) -- (5.1,0);

\draw (0.5,0.21) -- (1.5,0.21);
\draw (0.5,0.42) -- (1.5,0.42);
\draw (0.5,0.63) -- (1.5,0.63);
\draw (0.5,0.84) -- (1.5,0.84);
\draw (0.5,1.06) -- (1.5,1.06);

\draw (1.8,0.21) -- (3.2,0.21);
\draw (1.8,0.42) -- (3.2,0.42);
\draw (1.8,0.63) -- (3.2,0.63);
\draw (1.8,0.84) -- (3.2,0.84);
\draw (1.8,1.06) -- (3.2,1.06);

\draw (3.5,0.21) -- (4.9,0.21);
\draw (3.5,0.42) -- (4.9,0.42);
\draw (3.5,0.63) -- (4.9,0.63);
\draw (3.5,0.84) -- (4.9,0.84);
\draw (3.5,1.06) -- (4.9,1.06);

\draw (5.2,0.21) -- (6.6,0.21);
\draw (5.2,0.42) -- (6.6,0.42);
\draw (5.2,0.63) -- (6.6,0.63);
\draw (5.2,0.84) -- (6.6,0.84);
\draw (5.2,1.06) -- (6.6,1.06);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's too late in the evening to add a lot of explanations, but I'm adding a completely different suggestion for how to draw this. It is kind of quick and dirty, and could probably be written a lot better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
fulllinebox/.pic={
\node (-frame) at (0,0) [above right,draw,minimum width=1.6cm,minimum height=1.3cm] {};
\foreach \y in {0.167,0.334,...,1}
  \draw (-frame.south west) ++(0.1cm,1.3cm*\y) -- +(1.4cm,0);
},
halflinebox/.pic={
\node (-frame) at (0,0)  [above right,draw,minimum width=1.6cm,minimum height=1.3cm] {};
\foreach \y in {0.167,0.334,...,1}
  \draw (-frame.south west) ++(0.7cm,1.3cm*\y) -- +(0.8cm,0);
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace,mirror,amplitude=5pt}]
\pic (1) {halflinebox};
\pic (2) at ([xshift=0.2cm]1-frame.south east) {fulllinebox};
\pic (3) at ([xshift=0.2cm]2-frame.south east) {fulllinebox};
\pic (4) at ([xshift=0.2cm]3-frame.south east) {fulllinebox};

\draw [decorate] (1-frame.south west) ++(0.1cm,-1pt) -- node[below=5pt]{$S_m$} ++(1.4cm,0);
\draw [decorate] (4-frame.south west) ++(0.1cm,-1pt) -- node[below=5pt]{$S_1$} ++(1.4cm,0);

\path (2-frame.south east) --node[below=9pt] {$\dots$} (3-frame.south west);

\draw [latex-latex,shorten >=0.05cm,shorten <=0.05cm] ([yshift=0.1cm]4-frame.north west) -- node[above]{$l$} ([yshift=0.1cm]4-frame.north east);

\node [right,align=center] at (4-frame.east) {$x_1$\\$\vdots$\\$x_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Coordinates are a way to save the position of a coordinate to use it later. The *decorations.pathreplacing* library contains a `brace` decoration, which has to be `mirror`ed here (or you could reverse the order of the points specified). The *calc* library allows you to compute with (abstact) coordinates, like adding a certain amount (`($(N)+(x,y)$)`) or to specify a point a certain fraction along the way betweeen two points (`($(V)!x!(W)$)`). `stelth` is a certain kind of arrow tip, there are many others, see the manual or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction/42679#42679).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace, mirror}]
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (1.6,0) coordinate (B) -- (1.6,1.3) -- (0,1.3)  -- cycle;
\draw (1.7,0) -- (3.3,0) coordinate (C) -- (3.3,1.3) -- (1.7,1.3) -- cycle;
\draw (3.4,0) coordinate (D) -- (5,0) -- (5,1.3) -- (3.4,1.3) -- cycle;
\draw (5.1,0) coordinate (E) -- (6.7,0) coordinate (F) -- (6.7,1.3) coordinate (G) -- (5.1,1.3) coordinate (H) -- cycle;

\draw (0.5,0.21) -- (1.5,0.21);
\draw (0.5,0.42) -- (1.5,0.42);
\draw (0.5,0.63) -- (1.5,0.63);
\draw (0.5,0.84) -- (1.5,0.84);
\draw (0.5,1.06) -- (1.5,1.06);

\draw (1.8,0.21) -- (3.2,0.21);
\draw (1.8,0.42) -- (3.2,0.42);
\draw (1.8,0.63) -- (3.2,0.63);
\draw (1.8,0.84) -- (3.2,0.84);
\draw (1.8,1.06) -- (3.2,1.06);

\draw (3.5,0.21) -- (4.9,0.21);
\draw (3.5,0.42) -- (4.9,0.42);
\draw (3.5,0.63) -- (4.9,0.63);
\draw (3.5,0.84) -- (4.9,0.84);
\draw (3.5,1.06) -- (4.9,1.06);

\draw (5.2,0.21) -- (6.6,0.21);
\draw (5.2,0.42) -- (6.6,0.42);
\draw (5.2,0.63) -- (6.6,0.63);
\draw (5.2,0.84) -- (6.6,0.84);
\draw (5.2,1.06) -- (6.6,1.06);

\draw[decorate] ($(A)+(0,-0.1)$) -- ($(B)+(0,-0.1)$);
\node[below] at ($(A)!0.5!(B)+(0,-0.2)$) {$\Delta\epsilon$};

\node[below] at ($(C)!0.5!(D)$) {$\dots$};

\draw[decorate] ($(E)+(0,-0.1)$) -- ($(F)+(0,-0.1)$);
\node[below] at ($(E)!0.5!(F)+(0,-0.2)$) {$\Omega\varphi$};

\node[right] at (G) {$\tau_{\beta}$};
\node[right] at ($(F)!0.55!(G)$) {$\vdots$};
\node[right] at (F) {$\tau_{\nu}$};

\draw[stealth-stealth] ($(G)+(0,0.1)$) -- ($(H)+(0,0.1)$);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Also, as the lines all appear to be the same length, you could have a look at `\foreach` and the syntax for relative coordinates (`\draw (2,1) -- ++ (1,1)`;)

Answer (score 3):

One more alternative:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm,
  start chain = going right,
     A/.style = {draw, minimum width=16mm, minimum height=13mm, 
                 inner sep=1mm, node contents={},
                 on chain},
     B/.style = {decorate,
                 decoration={brace, raise=1mm, mirror,
                 pre=moveto, pre length=1mm,  post=moveto,post length=1mm},
                 thick},
   arr/.style = {thick, shorten < = 1mm, shorten > = 1mm}
                        ]
\node (n1)  [A];
    \foreach \i in {2,5,8,11}
    \draw[arr,shorten <=8mm] ($(n1.south west) + (0,\i mm)$) -- + (16mm,0);
\node (n2)  [A];
    \foreach \i in {2,5,8,11}
    \draw[arr]  ($(n2.south west) + (0,\i mm)$) -- + (16mm,0);
\node (n3)  [A];
    \foreach \i in {2,5,8,11}
    \draw[arr]  ($(n3.south west) + (0,\i mm)$) -- + (16mm,0);
\node (n4)  [A];
    \foreach \i in {2,5,8,11}
    \draw[arr]  ($(n4.south west) + (0,\i mm)$) -- + (16mm,0);

\draw[B] (n1.south west) -- node[below=2mm]{$S_m$} (n1.south east);
\draw[B] (n4.south west) -- node[below=2mm]{$S_1$} (n4.south east);

\draw[stealth-stealth,shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] 
    ([yshift=2mm] n4.north west) -- node[above] {$l$} + (16mm,0);

\node[align=left,right=0mm of n4]   {$x_1$\\$\vdots$\\$x_n$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example I employ  additional package  `chains` for set nodes in chain. For drawing lines in nodes the `\foreach` loop is used. For simplifying of lines drawing in nodes they are shorten by option `shorten >=...`, so for the coordinates can be used left and right node's borders.

Comment: What is your very last sentence supposed to say?

Comment: @TomBombadil, ups, there are missing "simple to", When I wrote this sentence, here was already time for sleep :-(  I will correct it.

Comment: Ah, much clearer. I was also quite tired and wasn't sure if it was just my sleep-deprived brain that had trouble understanding you ;-)