# Draw arrow on sides of triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=1pt] (0,5)-- (0,0);
    \draw [line width=1pt] (5,0)-- (0,5);
    \draw [line width=1pt] (0,0)-- (5,0);
    \draw [fill=black] (0,5) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.0,5.5) node {$A$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.0,-0.5) node {$B$};
    \draw [fill=black] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (5.0,-0.5) node {$C$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Question:

How can I draw direction arrow on each lines of triangle? (all possible style of arrows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I misread the question, but if you want to vary the type of the arrow you may want to use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799
\tikzset{->-/.style n args={2}{decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}] 
 \path  (0,5) node[bullet,label=above:$A$](A){}
  (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$B$](B) {}
  (5,0) node[bullet,label=below:$C$](C) {};
  \foreach \X/\Arrow [remember=\X as \LastX (initially C)]in
  {A/latex,B/stealth,C/>}
  {\draw[line width=1pt,->-={0.5}{\Arrow}] (\LastX) -- (\X);}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment: this draws three triangles. Is that what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39282/121799
\tikzset{->-/.style n args={2}{decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow[line width=1pt]{#2}}},postaction={decorate}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,inner sep=1.5pt,fill}] 
 \begin{scope}
  \path  (0,5) node[bullet,label=above:$A$](A){}
   (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$B$](B) {}
   (5,0) node[bullet,label=below:$C$](C) {};
   \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially C)] in  {A,B,C}
   {\draw[line width=1pt,->-={0.5}{latex}] (\LastX) -- (\X);}
  \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \path  (0,5) node[bullet,label=above:$A$](A'){}
   (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$B$](B') {}
   (5,0) node[bullet,label=below:$C$](C') {};
   \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially C')]in  {A',B',C'}
   {\draw[line width=1pt,->-={0.5}{stealth}] (\LastX) -- (\X);}
  \end{scope} 
  \begin{scope}[yshift=-6.6cm]
  \path  (0,5) node[bullet,label=above:$A$](A''){}
   (0,0) node[bullet,label=below:$B$](B'') {}
   (5,0) node[bullet,label=below:$C$](C'') {};
   \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX (initially C'')]in  {A'',B'',C''}
   {\draw[line width=1pt,->-={0.5}{>}] (\LastX) -- (\X);}
  \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No friend, you understand my question better And the answer that I had hoped for almost got to be found. Only one request is please give me three different codes with arrows(three triangle with arrows) that you mentioned.

Comment: Should i increase size of arrows? i am waiting.......

Comment: @Sandy The three different arrows are already in `\foreach \X/\Arrow [remember=\X as \LastX (initially C)]in
  {A/latex,B/stealth,C/>}`, where they are set as `latex`, `stealth` and standard types. Yes, you can make the arrows thicker e.g. by saying `{\arrow[line width=2pt]{#2}}}` instead of `{\arrow{#2}}}`.

Comment: Yes you gave it. my question is that you mentioned three different arrows in one triangle, i want three different triangle with same type of arrows. Please because  i am working first time.

Comment: Please provide full solution this will be great help for me.

Comment: @Sandy Yes, I will be happy to follow your request if I understand it. You want three triangles? If so, do they all have the same dimensions? Are the next to each other? Or do you want 3 arrow heads on a given edge?

Comment: In your solution there are three different arrows in one triangle right. Now I am looking for a triangle in which all sides have same type of arrows. Therefore, there will be three triangles

Comment: @Sandy I added a code with three triangles.

Comment: million trillion thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sandy Just for additional information, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42679/156344) is a (quite complete) list of available arrow tips.

Answer (score 4):

Using [TikZ: How to draw an arrow in the middle of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/tikz-how-to-draw-an-arrow-in-the-middle-of-the-line)

```
%\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [fill=black] (0,5) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.0,5.5) node {$A$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0.0,-0.5) node {$B$};
    \draw [fill=black] (5,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (5.0,-0.5) node {$C$};

\begin{scope}[very thick,decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}
    ] 
    \draw [line width=1pt,postaction={decorate}] (0,5)-- (0,0);
    \draw [line width=1pt,postaction={decorate}] (5,0)-- (0,5);
    \draw [line width=1pt,postaction={decorate}] (0,0)-- (5,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible of article document type?

Comment: @Sandy Yes...sure

Comment: Would you please modified your codes for article?

Comment: @Sandy done... see the code above....