# How to make the part of the rectangle wider than the red part in tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles

I have a figure where there is a train-test split visible.
However, I would like to make the red part 'wider' than the blue part, but I cannot find an option in shapes.multipart that allows me to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
state/.style={
       rectangle split,
       rectangle split parts=2,
       rectangle split part fill={blue!30,red!20},
       rounded corners,
       rectangle split horizontal,
       draw=black, thick,
       minimum height=6em,
       text width=0.8cm,
       minimum width=1.5em,
       inner sep=2pt,
       text centered,
       fill opacity=0.5
       }
}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [state] at (0,0) {Train \nodepart{two} Test } ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may use `\nodepart[text width=2cm]{two}` to specify the width of the red part.

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot! Where could I find the documentation for this? Can I also edit the blue part?

Comment: How could i place the text at the top of the rectangle? so a bit higher and not centered?

Comment: I did not look into the manual actually but used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42675/234654) as one good reference.

Comment: Well I did not find an elegant way to put it on the top, but change `Test` into `{\\[-3em]Test}` will at least give you that effect. Options in `\nodepart` are limited and not so flexible because I cannot use `text depth`.