# Change the style of graph vertex

Tags: tikz-styles, graphs, automata

I want to change the style of the vertex.

I want all the black filled vertex to be named vertices.

And all the vertices with double circles are now named as well.

That way:

[image]

This is the output I had:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}    

    \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.5cm,
        every node/.style={draw, fill, circle, inner sep=1.102pt},
        endnode/.style={fill=none, inner sep=5pt},
        every edge/.style={draw, ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
        itslabel/.style={draw=none, fill=none, above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize},
        ]
        % position the nodes a..d
        \node (a) [draw=none,fill=none] {I};
        \node (b) [right=of a] {};
        \node (c) [above right=of b] {};
        \node (d) [above right=of c] {};
        \node (e) [right=of d] {};
        \node (f) [right=of e] {};
        \node (g) [right=of f] {};
        \node (gend) [endnode] at (g) {};
        \node (h) [below right=of c] {};
        \node (i) [right=of h] {};
        \node (j) [right=of i] {};
        \node (k) [right=of j] {};
        \node (l) [right=of k] {};
        \node (m) [right=of l] {};
        \node (mend) [endnode] at (m) {};
        \node (n) [below right=of b] {};
        \node (o) [right=of n] {};
        \node (p) [right=of o] {};
        \node (q) [right=of p] {};
        \node (r) [right=of q] {};
        \node (s) [right=of r] {};
        \node (send) [endnode] at (s) {};
        
        
        %[shorten >=1em]    final
        \path (a.center) edge (b) 
        (b) edge node [itslabel, pos=0.38, above=5pt] {\(\varepsilon\)} (c)
        (c.center) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.4, above = 0.1] {\(\varepsilon\)} (d)
        (d) edge node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (e)
        (e) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (f)
        (f) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (g)
        (c) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.32, below = 0.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (h)
        (h) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (i)
        (i) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (j)
        (j) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (k)
        (k) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (l)
        (l) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (m)
        (b) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.32, below = 0.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (n)
        (n) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (o)
        (o) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (p)
        (p) edge node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (q)
        (q) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (r)
        (r) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (s);
        
        \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(g) + (0,.1cm)$)
        -- ++(0,.8cm) 
        -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (b);
        \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(m) + (0,-.1cm)$)
        -- ++(0,-2.5cm)
        -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} 
        ($(b) + (-.2cm,0)$);
        \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(s) + (0,-.1cm)$)
        -- ++(0,-.63cm)
        -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: First off, this is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Some packages and/or libraries are loaded more than once and many are useless for the purpose of your present graph. This is not your first post here, you should already have payed attention to those rules. Now to stay a bit more on topic, you may need to use the [chains library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction/43038#43038) to avoid all those `right = of`. Then you need to create node styles, using `tikzset`.

Comment: Additionally, when you put code in your question, can you put it all into a code block rather then text so it looks better and can be copy and pasted easier.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to do too many changes to your code, so I let it like that, not using `chains`.
I defined `endnode` differently, and since your request for the normal nodes is not clear enough to me, I tried to add what I thought you needed. Feel free to be more specific if that's not exactly what you want.

[image: vertex styles]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%automato
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{->,
    >=stealth,
    node distance = 3cm,
    every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10},
    initial text = $I$,
    auto rotate/.style={auto=right,->,
        to path={let \p1=(\tikztostart),\p2=(\tikztotarget),
            \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},\n2={\n1-10},\n3={\n1+190}
            in (\tikztostart.\n2) -- (\tikztotarget.\n3) \tikztonodes}}}
        
\begin{document}    

    \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.5cm,      
        endnode/.style={draw, circle, fill=none, inner sep=5pt, double},
        every edge/.style={draw, ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
        itslabel/.style={draw=none, fill=none, above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize},
        n1/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=5mm,font=\scriptsize},
        endnode/.style={n1, double, double distance=1.5pt},
        every node/.style={n1},        
        ]
    % position the nodes a..d
    \node (a) [draw=none,fill=none,font=\normalsize] {I};
    \node (b) [right=of a] {$g_1$};
    \node (c) [above right=of b] {$g_2$};
    \node (d) [above right=of c] {$g_3$};
    \node (e) [right=of d] {$g_4$};
    \node (f) [right=of e] {$g_5$};
    \node (g) [draw=none,right=of f] {};
    \node (gend) [endnode] at (g) {$g_6$};
    \node (h) [below right=of c] {};
    \node (i) [right=of h] {};
    \node (j) [right=of i] {};
    \node (k) [right=of j] {};
    \node (l) [right=of k] {};
    \node (m) [draw=none,right=of l] {};
    \node (mend) [endnode] at (m) {};
    \node (n) [below right=of b] {};
    \node (o) [right=of n] {};
    \node (p) [right=of o] {};
    \node (q) [right=of p] {};
    \node (r) [right=of q] {};
    \node (s) [draw=none,right=of r] {};
    \node (send) [endnode] at (s) {};
    
    
    %[shorten >=1em]    final
    \path (a.center) edge (b) 
    (b) edge node [itslabel, pos=0.38, above=5pt] {\(\varepsilon\)} (c)
    (c) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.4, above = 0.1] {\(\varepsilon\)} (d)
    (d) edge node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (e)
    (e) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (f)
    (f) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (g)
    (c) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.32, below = 0.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (h)
    (h) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (i)
    (i) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (j)
    (j) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (k)
    (k) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (l)
    (l) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (m)
    (b) edge node [itslabel, pos = 0.32, below = 0.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (n)
    (n) edge node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (o)
    (o) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (p)
    (p) edge node [itslabel] {\(1\)} (q)
    (q) edge node [itslabel] {\(\varepsilon\)} (r)
    (r) edge [shorten >=1em] node [itslabel] {\(0\)} (s);
    
    \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(g) + (0,.1cm)$)
    -- ++(0,.8cm) 
    -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (b);
    \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(m) + (0,-.1cm)$)
    -- ++(0,-2.5cm)
    -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} 
    ($(b) + (-.2cm,0)$);
    \draw[ ->, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt] ($(s) + (0,-.1cm)$)
    -- ++(0,-.63cm)
    -| node [itslabel, pos=.2] {\(\varepsilon\)} (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thank you.
But the figure has now increased in size and didn't fit in my document. Could you please bring the vertices closer together, decreasing the length of the edges?

Comment: @B612 Maybe try to change **node distance = 3cm**.

Comment: +1: The code for **auto rotate** looks pretty sophisticated. Did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner The code for auto rotate was into OP's initial post (edited since).